# List types defined by assembly without loading dependent assemblies

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies

I want to list the types (just the names of them) that are defined in an assembly.

I know how to load an assembly and use .GetTYpes(), but that fails if referenced assemblies are not also loaded.  I don't want to do that.

Ildasm does what I want.  I can point to to an assembly, and it will show me the types defined in that assembly, without loading another.  How does it do that?

Thanks,

Elroy

Answer (score 0):

You could try using either "ReflectionOnlyLoad" or Mono.Cecil.

Answer (score -1):

try loading for ReflectionOnly with [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx)

Comment: Tried that.  Didnt' work.  Still get an exception on LoadTypes()